# WiX: Require elevated privilege for perUser Install

Tags: wix

I want to author an install using WiX 3.9 with an install scope of `perUser`. However, I also need to install a font which requires elevated privilege.

I'm fine with the installer prompting for elevated privilege.

Is there a way to configure a WiX authored installer package with the scope as `perUser`, but still have it prompt for privilege elevation so the font can be installed?

And if this can be done, can the privilege elevation be conditional on whether the font is installed?

Comment: Are you talking about wix bootstraper or msi installer?

Comment: In the MSI installer.